# UseEffect unable to update useState properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update this state that is an empty list on start:

```
    const [winnerList, setWinnerList] = useState([]);
```

from a useEffect which will run once:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
  
  fetch("/players").then( res => res.json()).then(data => {

   if(data) {
    console.log(data);
    setWinnerList(JSON.parse(data));
    
    console.log(winnerList);
    window.localStorage.setItem('winner', JSON.stringify(winnerList));

    }
     }) 
    },[])
```

when I console.log (data) I get the json as expected **but** when I console log(winnerList) I get an empty array even though I setWinnerList with the json data.

after a

Comment: State updates are not synchronous. The state will update on next render. This is expected behaviour. You can use `data` to update localstorage, or do that from a `useEffect` on `winnerList`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `setWinnerList` is asynchronous. You can change the logic like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/players").then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
      setWinnerList(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  })
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
  console.log(winnerList);
  window.localStorage.setItem('winner', JSON.stringify(winnerList));
}, [winnerList]);
```

First `winnerList` should be updated, and after the new render has been occured, `useEffect` callback with `winnerList` dependency gets called.

Check out react documentation about [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and also there are a bunch of very good examples in beta.reactjs about [useEffect hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect).